# Symfony 1.3: Any opinion about this code? Could be shorter or better?

Tags: symfony1

I need your opinion about this code below.

I have a list of messages: each message has a link that change the state
of the message (read - non read).

In the partial "_message" i have this:

```
<div class="switching_link" id="switching_link_<?php echo $message ?>">

         echo include_partial('link_switch_state', array('message' =>
$message))

</div>
```

In the partial "_link_switch_state" i have this:

```
if((int)$message->getState() == 1) {

            $string_state_message="non read";

} else {

            $string_state_message="read";

}

echo link_to_remote('Mark as '.$string_state_message, array(

                    'url' => 'message/switchState?id='.$message->getId(),

                     'update' => 'switching_link_'.$message,

                     "complete" => "switchClassMessage('$message');",

));
```

And in message/actions/actions.class.php i have this:

```
public function executeSwitchState(sfWebRequest $request) {

         // searching the message we want to change its state.
         $this->messages =
Doctrine::getTable('Message')->findById($request->getParameter('id'));

         // changing the state of the message.
         if($this->messages[0]->getState() == 1) {

             $this->messages[0]->setState(0);
         }
         else {

             $this->messages[0]->setState(1);
         }

         $this->messages[0]->save();

         // rendering the partial that shows the link ("Mark as read/non
read").
         return $this->renderPartial('mensaje/link_switch_state', array(
'message' => $this->messages[0]));

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmh not sure if you can write it shorter in Symonfy, but you can get rid of the `if-else` statements (assuming that the `state` can either be `0` or `1`):

In `_message`:

```
$string_state_message = ($message->getState()) ? "non read" : "read";
```

`0` and `"0"` evaluate to `false`, any other non-empty string to `true`.

In `message/actions/actions.class.php`:

```
$this->messages[0]->setState(!$this->messages[0]->getState());
```

This is again due the fact that `0 == false` and `1 == true`.